# Recursive function of tree with infinite childs. c++

Tags: c++, recursion, tree, filesystems

I've created a virtual filesystem that i made to simulate a hard drive. The problem i am getting is that when i format this "drive" i need to go though every folder and sub-folders and delete "files" that I've created and then deleting the folders without getting memory leaks :) 
I've been at this for a few hours now and I've tried to make recursive functions but it won't delete everything. It keeps getting stuck somewhere :(

Any ideas would make my week!! Thanks.

Here is code example of my folder.h and recursive function.

folder.h :

```
#ifndef FOLDER_H
#define FOLDER_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "file.h"
using namespace std;
class folder
{
private:
    int CAP = 10;

    int nrOfChildFolders;
    int nrOfFiles;
    string folderName;
    folder * parentFolder;
    folder * childFolder[10];
    file * fileArray[10];



public:
    folder();
    folder(string folderName, folder * parent);
    ~folder();
    void addFolder(string folderName);
    void addFile(string fileName, int nr);
    string getFolderAndFiles()const;
    string getFolderName()const;
    int getFileNr(string fileName)const;
    void reset();
    folder * getFolder(string name)const; 
    folder * getParentFolder()const;
    void deleteFile(string name, int nr);
    folder * getChildFolder(int pos);
    int getNrOfChildFolders()const;

    /* data */
};
#endif
```

Recursive function :

```
void FileSystem::recursiveFolderSwitcher(folder * newCurrentFolder) 
{
    int folders = newCurrentFolder->getNrOfChildFolders();
    if (newCurrentFolder->getNrOfChildFolders() != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < folders; i++) 
        {
            newCurrentFolder = newCurrentFolder->getChildFolder(i);
            recursiveFolderSwitcher(newCurrentFolder);
        }
    } 
    newCurrentFolder->reset(); 
}
```

Thanks <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reassigning `newCurrentFolder` in your for-loop.

```
newCurrentFolder = newCurrentFolder->getChildFolder(i);
```

This makes the final

```
newCurrentFolder->reset()
```

reset the last child instead.

Use

```
folder* child = newCurrentFolder->getChildFolder(i);
recursiveFolderSwitcher(child);
```

instead.

Also

```
if (newCurrentFolder->getNrOfChildFolders() != 0)
```

is unnecessary, the for-statement will take care of this for you.